# camel-http4 proxy setting spring xml

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

I'm having issues even performing a http request and wondering ... do you provide the leading HTTP:// in setting the proxy settings? is this correct? or do you leave out the http:// ? thank you!

```
  <properties>
       <property key="http.proxyHost" value="http://PITC-Zscaler-Americas-Cincinnati.proxy.corp.com"/>
       <property key="http.proxyPort" value="80"/>
  </properties>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it it you do not apply the protocol http:// - I have tried it with using the IP address doing a nslookup, found the IP, this worked. I also, then used the cononical name without the leading protocol, and it also worked.

so, I guess then answer is no, you do not use the leading protocol for defining the http.proxyHost.

thanks everyone, hope this helps someone.

```
  <properties>
       <property key="http.proxyHost" value="canonical name - NO leading http://"/>
       <property key="http.proxyPort" value="80"/>
  </properties>

  <properties>
       <property key="http.proxyHost" value="IP Address"/>
       <property key="http.proxyPort" value="80"/>
  </properties>
```